# Keyof nested child objects

Tags: typescript

I have a recursively typed object that I want to get the keys of and any child keys of a certain type.

For instance. Below I want to get a union type of:

```
'/another' | '/parent' | '/child'
```

Example:

```
export interface RouteEntry {
    readonly name: string,
    readonly nested : RouteList | null
}
export interface RouteList {
    readonly [key : string] : RouteEntry
}

export const list : RouteList = {
    '/parent': {
        name: 'parentTitle',
        nested: {
            '/child': {
                name: 'child',
                nested: null,
            },
        },
    },
    '/another': {
        name: 'anotherTitle',
        nested: null
    },
}
```

In typescript you can use keyof typeof RouteList to get the union type:

```
'/another' | '/parent'
```

Is there a method to also include the nested types

Answer (score 13):

Here's an infinitely recursive solution:

```js
type Paths<T> = T extends RouteList
  ? keyof T | { [K in keyof T]: Paths<T[K]['nested']> }[keyof T]
  : never

type ListPaths = Paths<typeof list> // -> "/parent" | "/another" | "/child"
```

Tested on Typescript v3.5.1. Also you need to remove the type annotation from the `list` variable as advised by @jcalz.

Comment: I like this answer (and might have given some version of it recently) but I wish I knew that such things were officially supported.  Recursively pushing a property down one level in a type is safe because such types are lazily evaluated, but recursively indexing into an object (pulling the property up a level) can be a problem because such types are eagerly evaluated.

Comment: This is really laconic answer

Comment: It works but it's dangerous to use and probably removed one day as is mentioned somewhere in TypeScript issues.

Comment: @DanielSteigerwald: Could you point out where this is mentioned in the typescript issues or even just give some hnits as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 11):

That's a tough one.  TypeScript lacks <strike>both [mapped conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424) and</strike>  general [recursive type definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496), which are both what I'd want to use to give you that union type. (Edit 2019-04-05: [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) were introduced in TS2.8) There are some sticking points with what you want:

- The `nested` property of a `RouteEntry` can sometimes be `null`, and type expressions that evaluate to `keyof null` or `null[keyof null]` start to break things.  One needs to be careful.  My workaround involves adding a dummy key so that it's never null, and then removing it at the end.
- Whatever type alias you use (call it `RouteListNestedKeys<X>`) seems to need to be defined in terms of itself, and you will get a "circular reference" error. A workaround would be to provide something that works up to some finite level of nesting (say, 9 levels deep).  This might cause the compiler to slow way down, since it could eagerly evaluate all 9 levels instead of deferring the evaluation until later.
- This needs a lot of type alias composition involving mapped types, and there is a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15756) with composing mapped types that won't be fixed until TypeScript 2.6.  A [workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17908#issuecomment-323596268) involves using generic default type parameters.
- The "remove a dummy key at the end" step involves a type operation called [`Diff`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-307871458) which needs at least TypeScript 2.4 to run properly.

All that means: I have a solution which works, but I warn you, it's complex and crazy.  One last thing before I drop in the code: you need to change

```
export const list: RouteList = { // ...
```

to

```
export const list = { // ...
```

That is, remove the type annotation from the `list` variable.  If you specify it as `RouteList`, you are throwing away TypeScript's knowledge of the exact structure of `list`, and you will get nothing but `string` as the key type.  By leaving off the annotation, you let TypeScript infer the type, and therefore it will remember the entire nested structure.

Okay, here goes:

```
type EmptyRouteList = {[K in 'remove_this_value']: RouteEntry};
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[K in T]: K} &
  {[K in U]: never} & { [K: string]: never })[T];
type N0<X extends RouteList> = keyof X
type N1<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N0<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N2<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N1<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N3<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N2<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N4<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N3<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N5<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N4<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N6<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N5<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N7<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N6<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N8<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N7<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type N9<X extends RouteList, Y = {[K in keyof X]: N8<X[K]['nested'] & EmptyRouteList>}> = keyof X | ValueOf<Y> 
type RouteListNestedKeys<X extends RouteList, Y = Diff<N9<X>,'remove_this_value'>> = Y;
```

Let's try it out:

```
export const list = {
    '/parent': {
        name: 'parentTitle',
        nested: {
            '/child': {
                name: 'child',
                nested: null,
            },
        },
    },
    '/another': {
        name: 'anotherTitle',
        nested: null
    },
}

type ListNestedKeys = RouteListNestedKeys<typeof list>
```

If you inspect `ListNestedKeys` you will see that it is `"parent" | "another" | "child"`, as you wanted.  It's up to you whether that was worth it or not.

Whew!  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: One minor detail: if you remove index signature `readonly [key : string] : RouteEntry` from `RouteList` this all still works. Apparently that index signature is never used in type inference when you provide actual generic argument as  `typeof list`. This allows you to write `extends {}` instead of `extends RouteList` everywhere, and remove `RouteList` interface from the answer completely.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Aleksi shows how to obtain the requested type union `"/parent" | "/another" | "/child"`.

Since the question deals with a route hierarchy i would like to add that since typescript 4.1 the feature [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) can be used to not only obtain all keys but to even generate **all possible routes**: `"/parent" | "/another" | "/parent/child"`

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type AllPaths<T extends RouteList, Path extends string = ''> = ValueOf<{
    [K in keyof T & string]: 
        T[K]['nested'] extends null 
        ? K 
        : (`${Path}${K}` | `${Path}${K}${AllPaths<Extract<T[K]['nested'], RouteList>>}`)
}>

type AllRoutes = AllPaths<typeof list> // -> "/parent" | "/another" | "/parent/child"
```

Like the other answers mention the `list` object may not have the `RouteList` type annotation as it would erase the type information our `AllPaths` type operates on.