# Type as string path of object keys

Tags: typescript

```
interface Obj {
  a: any;
  b: {
   c: any;
   d: any;
  }
  c: {
    d: any;
  }[];
}
```

```
get(obj: Obj, path: string) {
}
```

I'd like to type the `path` to force user to pass only keys available in the `obj`.
`get(obj: Obj, path: keyof Obj){}` works only for the first level.

Expected result is being able to pass as the path:
`a`, `b`, `b.c`, `b.d`, `c`, `c[0]`, `c[0].d`. Is typescript's way of typing able to solve this problem?

Comment: That's a hard one. Maybe this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971032/keyof-nested-child-objects

Comment: No, that's not possible.