# Typescript: Can you recursively type an object

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to have typescript infer the type of an object's keys and the keys of it's children recursively. For example given the declaration below:

```
const o:A<X> = {
  a:'1',
  b: {
    c: '2'
  }
}
```

I'd like to define `A` so that `X` will be `"a"|"b"|"c"`. Using `keyof` I can get Typescript to infer the first layer (i.e. `X = "a"|"b"`) but not subsequent ones. Is it possible to get Typescript to infer the key types of the grandchild nodes?

Comment: If you're trying to take an object like `const o = {a:'1', b: {c: '2'}}` and use a type function like `DeepKeyof<typeof o>` evaluate to `"a"|"b"|"c"` then this is a duplicate of [Keyof nested child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971032/keyof-nested-child-objects). If, on the other hand, you're trying to define a type `A` such that `o` is assignable to type `A<"a"|"b"|"c">` then @bsapaka's answer below would apply.  Which one do you want?

Comment: @jcalz: thanks for clarifying. Mostly I was interested in the former but both are useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
type A<X extends string|number> = {
  [id in X]?: string | A<X>
}
```