# Typescript - keyof values of array

Tags: typescript, dynamic, types, union

I have a list

```js
export const list = [
  {
    name: 'parentTitle',
  },
  {
    name: 'anotherTitle',
  },
  {
    name: 'whatever',
  },
];
```

Now I want to create dynamically a union type which describes the following:

```js
type Title = 'parentTitle' | 'anotherTitle' | 'whatever';
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to adapt the idea here: [Keyof nested child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971032/keyof-nested-child-objects)
But I can't figuring it out

Answer (score 7):

The type of `list` in your example gets inferred by the compiler to be `Array<{name: string}>`, and thus the compiler has completely forgotten the particular [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) of the `name` properties by the time you try to define `Title`.

You'll have to change how you assign `list`, at least somewhat.  The easiest thing to do (which may or may not meet your needs) is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions), which asks the compiler to infer the narrowest type possible:

```
export const list = [
    { name: 'parentTitle', },
    { name: 'anotherTitle', },
    { name: 'whatever', },
] as const;
```

Now `list` is inferred to be of type:

```
/* 
const list: readonly [
    { readonly name: "parentTitle";}, 
    { readonly name: "anotherTitle";}, 
    { readonly name: "whatever";}
]
*/
```

which is a readonly tuple of readonly objects with particular `name` properties in a particular order.  From that we can use [lookup types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to define `Title`:

```
type Title = typeof list[number]["name"];
// type Title = "parentTitle" | "anotherTitle" | "whatever"
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wDYEt1wLxwDaAUHGXAN5zICGAtsAFxwDkYNUwyMAKljBmAsANHAC+w0uSq0GzFjWQQYAC2BQ+AoaIlSyM+k1YB3FTRjAAbupHjJAXTg1UiFOgDcpYgHoAVHGIkNEwcGGZOGgATFAwATyI9SjgI6OQ46kNmACJ2Tm5NQSz3CQDyJJSY+NkjLMVlNQ1+QuLRRKoKtKrMuCzTcyt1IrFie2Jfb2JiGFiwYDgCuYJp2YgAMzhsdEJkAFc6ACN1e0Is6qz7T29vOGW5hfwe3K5eJuAsuAAfHrrVdQX3r69MwWaxQLJAA)

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! But I think I have another case. I'm importing the list from a .json File and not directly in typescript. But I can't define the list of the json File with `as const` as you suggested. Is there a way to do this with a list from a json file?
import list from './list.json';
type Title = typeof list[number]['name'];

Comment: Please edit the question code to be a [mcve] if importing JSON is a requirement; I'm afraid that options for importing JSON are limited.  There is a [request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063) to be able to import a json file `as const`, but it's not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as this:

```
type GetNameFromList<T extends readonly {name: string}[]> = T[number]['name'];
const list = [
  {
    name: 'parentTitle',
  },
  {
    name: 'anotherTitle',
  },
  {
    name: 'whatever',
  },
] as const;

//here is what you want
type values = GetNameFromList<typeof list>;  // 'parentTitle' | 'anotherTitle' | 'whatever'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an interface for it and make an array type from it.

```
interface Title {
    name: 'parentTitle' | 'anotherTitle' | 'whatever';
}

let list: Title[] = [
  {
    name: 'parentTitle',
  },
  {
    name: 'anotherTitle',
  },
  {
    name: 'whatever',
  },
];
```